# Is it possible to dynamically force index usage in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

Good day,

Per the title, 
Is it possible to dynamically force the usage of a certain index in a query?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

- I have a temporary table called #Employees
- This table does not yet have indexes set to it.
- There is a non-temporary table called Employees
- This non-temporary table has an index on the "Month" column.
- This is a simplification of my environment, which stems mostly from Sybase deciding not to use the index unless I force it.
- @index has been set by previous code to be either the inid, or the exact index name. I tried both.
- No changes to the non-temporary table are allowed.

*Table:

```
EmployeeID(numeric) | EmployeeName(varchar) | Month(datetime) | Sallary(int)
```

Query:

```
insert into #Employees 
select * from Employees (index @index)
where Month between 'Jan' and 'Dec'
```

With this code, Sybase simply says there is an error near @index.

```
Q1: Can I do this?  
Q2: If so, how? 
Q3: If not, is there anything else I can do?
```

The query will NOT complete unless that index is used, and the inid I know with 100% certainty is not the same in all servers this needs to run on, and although I did not check, there is also no guarantee the index name itself is the same.
I have a query that can find this index, based on its column, the column name being something I can assure will always be the same.

Thanks in advance,
ziv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you must use a hard-coded index name when providing the hint.  For example, if the index on the month column were called `month_index` then the following would work:

```
insert into #Employees 
select * from Employees (index month_index)
where Month between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
```

But if you specify no index then Sybase might use whatever single inxex you have as a default.

Comment: Good day Tim,
Regarding the use of the index name. As our R&D department continues to mess around with indexes, there is no guarantee that the index will always have the same name. The only think that is assured, is that the column of it will always be the same.
Regarding the datetime thing, I just put 'Jan' and 'Dec' as placeholders. They are non-important to the code, beyond the fact that I do have a datetime based where clause.

Comment: Well, "no", is also an answer. I will continue to wait, for now, thank you for your time.

Comment: @ziv Try the dynamic SQL above.  It it doesn't work, then I would be leaning towards "no"

Comment: Thank you Tim, but I already tried it that way, and got the same result.

Comment: Ok, after some more fiddling around, I got it to use the right index on it's own. It turns out, if I ran it in dynamic SQL, even if I don't specify an index, it still uses one, and it's the right one. I suppose since it's running at the end of things, it has a chance to make a better plan...